# A regular expression that match only words that do not combine numbers and letters

Tags: java, regex

As example I have the following sentence: k8s Kubernetes.

Given the following regular expression: `[a-zA-Z]+[^\da-zA-Z]`

Actual result(match bold characters): k8**s Kubernetes**.

Expected result(match bold characters): k8s **Kubernetes**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the word boundary `\b` to delimitate a word and ignore numbers, like:

`\b[A-Za-z]+\b`

Test: https://regexr.com/51oe7